# VS2019: [C6386][C6001] warnings on modified counting sort

Tags: c++, sorting, visual-c++, counting-sort

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void MCounting_Sort(vector<int>& A)
{
const int size = A.size();

int min = A[0];
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    if (A[i] < min)
        min = A[i];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    A[i] = A[i] - min;

int max = A[0];
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    if (A[i] > max)
        max = A[i];

int* C = new int[max + 1]{ 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] + 1;

int* B = new int[size];
int pos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < max + 1; i++)
    if (C[i] > 0)
        for (int j = 0; j < C[i]; j++)
            B[pos++] = i;   // <-- C6386 Buffer overrun...
        
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    A[i] = B[i] + min;   // <-- C6001 Using uninitialized memory "B"

delete[] B;
delete[] C;
}

int main()
{
vector<int> A {7,2,18,5};
for(unsigned int i=0; i<A.size(); i++) cout<<A[i]<<" ";
cout<<endl;
MCounting_Sort(A);
for(unsigned int i=0; i<A.size(); i++) cout<<A[i]<<" ";
}
```

output:

```
7 2 18 5 
2 5 7 18
```

The sorting algorithm works (also for negative numbers), but I get these two warnings, I'm not sure if I can fix them, because the algorithm itself probably isn't good, but it's a school assignment. Maybe I did write something wrong though.

Comment: You allocate `int* B = new int[size];`, but never initialize these values. Any particular reason why you don't use a `std::vector<int>` for `B` as well?

Comment: For the 6001 warning, you are looping from 0 to `size`, however, `B` has only been initialized from 0 to `pos`, which is not guaranteed to be greater than or equal size. This has a similar effect for the 6386 warning.

Comment: Don't use owning raw pointers. Replace `B` and `C` with `std::vector`. Side effect: in a debug build you will get bounds checks at runtime.

Comment: The reason I don't use vector is because the assignment says I need to create "arrays" of certain size and I don't know how to do that with vectors.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in the comments to your question, your code would be far better if you avoided using 'raw' pointers and made use of the containers provided by the STL.

However, as it happens, the two warnings that the MSVC gives can be readily addressed by a 'trivial' modification to a single line of your code.

You can simply add an initializer list to your allocation of the `B` data (as you have done for `C`) and ensure that you allocate *at least* 2 integers in that array. The latter would normally be achieved using an expression like `std::max(size, 2)` inside the `[]` of the `new` call; however, as you have defined a local variable called `max`, you cannot use that function.

Instead, you can just change this line:

```cpp
int* B = new int[size];
```

to this:

```cpp
int* B = new int[size < 2 ? 2 : size] { 0 }; // Ensure at least 2 elements and initialize
```

---

As a side note, you may like to read this: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073)  Because, if you replace your `using namespace std;` line with individual `using` statements for *only* those STL elements that you actually use, then you can have both a local variable called `max` *and* use the `std::max(size, 2)` expression in your `new` call.

The following three lines will serve as a suitable replacement:

```cpp
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

Or, if your compiler conforms to the C++17 (or a later) Standard, you can put all three in one statement:

```cpp
using std::vector, std::cout, std::endl;
```